# How to fetch a Tag from jQuery Linkfy & store it into another table

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the jQuery linkfy to create a Tweet like functionality, Here I want to store only tag from the text area into the tag table. Is there any way out to to perform this? Below is my code snippet for jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toHashtagUrl(hashtag) {
return "/search?q=" + hashtag;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("form input[type='submit']").click(function() {
str = this.form.tweet_title.value
jQuery("#tweet_content").html(str);
var s= jQuery("#tweet_content").linkify(toHashtagUrl);


document.getElementById('tweet_title').value = s[0].innerHTML;

});
});
</script>
```

**View File**

```
<%= form_for(@tweet, :remote => true) do |f| %>
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
 <div id="tweet_content" style="display:none;"></div>
<tr>
  <td align="left" valign="top">
    <div class="labeldiv">Title</div>
    <%= f.text_area :title, :rows=>2 %>
  </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="top">
      <%= f.submit "Save", :class=>"btn btn-primary" %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

**Output**
 If I entered the below text into the text area the #tag1 & #tag2 needs to be stored in the Tag table & "Test" needs to be stored in tweet table.

"**Test #tag1 #tag2**"

any help will be a great relief !